# Swift Gesture Recognizer by adding subview

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uinavigationbar, addsubview

I have added a button to my navigationBar in titleView position.
I have then added a subview to this button.
I am trying to add a gesture recognizer associated with this view (UIImageView) but the tap is not detected.
Is it because is in the NavigationBar?
Is there a way to make it work?

Here's my code:

```
func createHeaderButton() {
    headerTitleBtn.setTitle(headerTitleBtnString, for: .normal)
    headerTitleBtn.titleLabel?.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
    headerTitleBtn.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 2
    headerTitleBtn.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
    let buttonImage = UIImageView()
    buttonImage.frame = CGRect(x: headerTitleBtn.frame.size.width, y: headerTitleBtn.frame.size.height/2 - 6, width: 12, height: 12)
    buttonImage.image = UIImage(named:"arrowDown")
    buttonImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    buttonImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    buttonImage.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    headerTitleBtn.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    let tapHedaerBtn = UIGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(headerBtnTapped))
    buttonImage.addGestureRecognizer(tapHedaerBtn)
    headerTitleBtn.addSubview(buttonImage)
}
@objc func headerBtnTapped() {
    print("here<")
}
```

and I call this function in viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear

Thank you

--------------------------- UPDATE
Here's my solution:
I change the code so i don't need to add a gesture recognizer and to everything on the button:

```
    func createHeaderButton() {
    headerTitleBtn.setTitle(headerTitleBtnString, for: .normal)
    headerTitleBtn.titleLabel?.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
    headerTitleBtn.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 2
    headerTitleBtn.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
    headerTitleBtn.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    headerTitleBtn.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 0)
    headerTitleBtn.setImage(UIImage(named:"arrowDown"), for: .normal)
    headerTitleBtn.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 15, bottom: 8, right: 8)
    headerTitleBtn.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    headerTitleBtn.imageView?.tintColor = UIColor.white
    headerTitleBtn.tintColor = UIColor.white
}
```

Comment: Check all `isUserInteractionEnabled` to each `superview` of `buttonImage`. Are they all to `true`?

Comment: why are you adding an imageView as the subview in Button?

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani I am trying to have a button with a title and an arrow on his right

Comment: @Larme is enabled on all the navigation bar

Comment: You are on the wrong path.
Try to set both image and title for the button.

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani i tried to use setImage... but it gets a mess to define the image dimension... any advise?

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani trying to achieve this: https://prnt.sc/gw1sz8

Comment: `myButton.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10,10,10,10)` same for image

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani this is what happens with the set image and the contentInsets to 10 :http://prntscr.com/gw1usm

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani and i don't understand why but it also change the color of the image

Comment: It is quite simple I am answering to your question.

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani Thank you for helping

Comment: Are you trying a make custom title of NavigationBar Right?

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani well i'm customizing the navigation bar... but i added it with a navigation controller... so i'm not adding the bar... i just added a button instead of the titleView... probably that was the mistake...